# Encrypt / Decrypt in asp.net using RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider

Tags: asp.net, encryption, rsaprotectedconfiguration

The encryption worked properly. But now i am getting an error that says "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider Bad Data" When checked, i came to know that we need to run the command: 
aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"

My question is, if I run this command in my production environment, will it affect any other websites thats hosted in the same server. Since its an update to the machine.config file will ther be any chnace that some other things will be affected?

Comment: It is possible that this question would get more/better attention on serverfault.

Comment: Not really a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

It won't (should not) because that command does not modify the machine.config file, but an ACL that controls which accounts have access to the key container. You can read more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxw286t2.aspx

This is a sentence from the article

*"By default, RSA key containers are tightly protected by NTFS access control lists (ACLs) on the server where they are installed. This improves the security of the encrypted information by restricting who can access the encryption key."*

As for your specific error, I just worked with web.config file encryption a few days back, and I recall receiving the Bad data error at one point. After a couple of times of repeating the setup steps, I was able to make it work, but I can't confirm which step made it work. My guesses for your case are:

1. You imported the wrong key file (the exported XML from the original container) into the container on that machine.
2. The data value on the config was messed with.
3. The account that is trying to decrypt the config file does not have privileges to that key container. In that case, the command that you ask about is the one to give access to a given account.
4. You could be referencing a different key container on your configProtectedData section. Hadn't though of this, and I'm not sure if you would get that specific Bad Data error, but it's a thought.

Hope you solved after all. Even though the question is old, I thought the answer might help someone.